# Emulate drag type text/plain behavior in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable, contenteditable

If you drag e.g. text/plain or text/html, your contenteditable element that you want to drop on places the caret/cursor at the position where you would drop the dragged content.

A very basic fiddle to show what I mean: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nspTj/)

```
<div contenteditable="true">DROP TEXT HERE</div>
This text wants to be dropped.
```

How can I emulate this behavior for custom datatypes? Or: How can I always put the caret next to the mouse-pointer while hovering?

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS :empty pseudo selector for that

```
[contenteditable="true"] {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    min-height: 1em;
}
[contenteditable="true"]:empty:before {
    content: 'DROP TEXT HERE';
    color: #999;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/dmitrismirnov/nspTj/1/)